# Parsing issue with parens. Parsec - Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

This is my code:

```
expr :: Parser Integer
expr = buildExpressionParser table factor <?> "expression"

table :: [[ Operator Char st Integer ]]
table = [
    [ op "*" (*) AssocLeft],
    [ op "+" (+) AssocLeft]
    ]
  where
    op s f assoc = Infix (do { string s ; return f }) assoc

factor = do { char '(' ; x <- expr ; char ')' ; return x }
    <|> number
    <?> "simple expression"


number :: Parser Integer
number = do { ds <- many1 digit; return read(ds))) } <?> "number"
```

This works perfectly with expressions like this: (10+10) * 10.
But I have a problem with the following: 10 +10)
This has to return a parsing error (just 1 parenthesis at the end), but instead it returns 20.

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `eof` parser to make sure you've read the whole input:

```
myParser = do
    parsed <- expr
    eof
    return parsed
```

If you're using `Control.Applicative` this can be simplified to:

```
myParser = expr <* eof
```